How to Style Button in Iced 0.12?
I'm new to Rust language and I want to style my button so it can be disabled when the process is still running.
I use iced 0.12.1.
This is my code snippet:
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct CustomButtonStyle;

impl StyleSheet for CustomButtonStyle {
    type Style = ();

    fn active(&self, _: &Self::Style) -> Appearance {
        Appearance {
            background: Some(Background::Color(Color::from_rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.2))),
            text_color: Color::WHITE,
            border: Border::default(),
            shadow: Shadow::default(),
            shadow_offset: Vector::default(),
        }
    }

    fn hovered(&self, _: &Self::Style) -> Appearance {
        Appearance {
            background: Some(Background::Color(Color::from_rgb(0.3, 0.7, 0.3))),
            text_color: Color::WHITE,
            border: Border::default(),
            shadow: Shadow::default(),
            shadow_offset: Vector::default(),
        }
    }

    fn disabled(&self, _: &Self::Style) -> Appearance {
        Appearance {
            background: Some(Background::Color(Color::from_rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))),
            text_color: Color::from_rgb(0.7, 0.7, 0.7),
            border: Border::default(),
            shadow: Shadow::default(),
            shadow_offset: Vector::default(),
        }
    }
}

...
                    button("Process")
                      .on_press(Message::Process)
                      .padding(Padding::from(5))
                      .style(CustomButtonStyle) //ERROR
...

The error said:

the trait bound iced::theme::Button: From<CustomButtonStyle> is not satisfied
required for CustomButtonStyle to implement Into<iced::theme::Button>

Full Error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `iced::theme::Button: From<CustomButtonStyle>` is not satisfied
   --> src\test_rust.rs:332:32
    |
332 |                         .style(CustomButtonStyle)
    |                          ----- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<CustomButtonStyle>` is not implemented for `iced::theme::Button`, which is required by `CustomButtonStyle: Into<_>`
    |                          |
    |                          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = note: required for `CustomButtonStyle` to implement `Into<iced::theme::Button>`
note: required by a bound in `iced::widget::Button::<'a, Message, Theme, Renderer>::style`
   --> C:\Users\\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\iced_widget-0.12.3\src\button.rs:127:40
    |
127 |     pub fn style(mut self, style: impl Into<Theme::Style>) -> Self {
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Button::<'a, Message, Theme, Renderer>::style`

I searched and found this: https://github.com/iced-rs/iced/issues/882
So I tried:
.style(iced::theme::Button::CustomButtonStyle)

And got this error:

no variant or associated item named CustomButtonStyle found for enum iced::theme::Button in the current scope
variant or associated item not found in Button

Full error:
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<CustomButtonStyle as StyleSheet>::Style == Theme`
   --> src\frontend_desktop.rs:331:60
    |
331 |                         .style(iced::theme::Button::custom(CustomButtonStyle))
    |                                --------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type mismatch resolving `<CustomButtonStyle as StyleSheet>::Style == Theme`
    |                                |
    |                                required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
note: expected this to be `Theme`
   --> src\test_rust.rs:15:18
    |
15  |     type Style = ();
    |                  ^^
note: required by a bound in `iced::theme::Button::custom`
   --> C:\Users\\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\iced_style-0.12.1\src\theme.rs:311:46
    |
310 |     pub fn custom(
    |            ------ required by a bound in this associated function
311 |         style_sheet: impl button::StyleSheet<Style = Theme> + 'static,
    |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Button::custom`

I also tried to change the
type Style = iced::theme::Button::Custom;

Got error that told me to either:

crate::frontend_desktop::theme::Custom
iced::theme::Custom
iced_style::theme::Custom

Then I follow:
type Style = iced::theme::Custom;

And got error for both "type Style" line and ".style(___)" line.
The full error for line "type Style":
error[E0277]: the trait bound `iced::theme::Custom: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
  --> src\test_rust.rs:14:18
   |
14 |     type Style = iced::theme::Custom;
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `iced::theme::Custom`
   |
note: required by a bound in `iced::widget::button::StyleSheet::Style`
  --> C:\Users\\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\iced_style-0.12.1\src\button.rs:34:17
   |
34 |     type Style: Default;
   |                 ^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `StyleSheet::Style`


Can you paste the full error? That will make things a bit clearer.

@nneonneo, I have updated and posted the full error.

Thanks. Sorry to be annoying, but errors need to go in code blocks, not in quote blocks (quote blocks mess up the formatting which makes them really hard to read).

@nneonneo. I tried using code blocks, but it looks the same as using quote blocks. So I screenshot the errors. Hope it helps!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I believe for iced 0.12 you need to do the following:

set Style = iced::Theme
call .style(iced::theme::Button::custom(CustomButtonStyle))

You’re getting errors because your button uses the default theme, so you need to provide a style from the default theme. Thankfully they provide a custom variant that lets you supply your own style - but you need to properly wrap your custom style in that variant.
Note that iced 0.13 appears to change the way .style works entirely.

I see. This one works. Thank you!

How about:
pub fn custom(_: &Theme, status: Status) -> Style {
    match status {
        Status::Active | Status::Pressed => Style {
            background: Some(Background::Color(Color::from_rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.2))),
            text_color: Color::WHITE,
            border: Border::default(),
            shadow: Shadow::default(),
        },
        Status::Hovered => Style {
            background: Some(Background::Color(Color::from_rgb(0.3, 0.7, 0.3))),
            text_color: Color::WHITE,
            border: Border::default(),
            shadow: Shadow::default(),
        },
        Status::Disabled => Style {
            background: Some(Background::Color(Color::from_rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))),
            text_color: Color::from_rgb(0.7, 0.7, 0.7),
            border: Border::default(),
            shadow: Shadow::default(),
        },
    }
}

And then:
button("Process")
 .on_press(Message::Process)
 .padding(Padding::from(5))
 .style(custom)


There's no iced::widget::button::Style, only iced::widget::button::StyleSheet. Do you mean StyleSheet? And in iced::event::Status there's no "Active", "Hovered", or "Disabled". Only "Ignored" and "Captured" (https://docs.rs/iced/latest/iced/event/enum.Status.html)

https://docs.rs/iced/0.13.1/iced/widget/button/struct.Style.html

Umm.. Do you know why I got this error...?
"unresolved import iced::widget::button::Style
|| consider importing this enum instead:
|| iced::font::Style"

widget::button::Style was added in version 0.13, what version are you using?

@Jmb, right- I missed that OP mentioned using iced 0.12.

Yeah it’s a bit unfortunate that the interfaces are so unstable, but it is a 0.x crate. I believe the new style approach in 0.13 is more intuitive, even if it’s somewhat less declarative.
